# Import classes from another package Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My source code directory (named `my_dir`) is organized as follow:

```
my_dir
|
|-- pkg_1
|    |
|    |-- module_1.py
|    |-- module_2.py
|
|-- src.py
```

In `module_1.py`, I import `module_2.py` by

```
import module_2
```

But when I import `module_1` in `src.py` by

```
import module_1
```

An error is raised as the statement `import module_2` in `module_1.py` acts as if my working directory is `pkg_1` instead of `my_dir`.

How can it fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

in `module_1.py` import it as `from . import module_2` and in `src.py` import module_1 as `from pkg_1 import module_1`

Comment: According to this approach, I need to change all import statements in `pkg_1` and maybe it's infeasible. My situation is that I've downloaded a repo from git and I want to use it as a module of my whole project. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: then in pkg_1 write __init__.py file and in this file wite `from . import module_1`  and `from . import module_2` then from `src.py` you can import it as `from pkg_1 import module_1`

Comment: @HOANGGIANG It is correct to change all the code if you want all the code to behave differently. You are taking a shortcut through the woods and complaining that there is no road on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause of the misunderstanding:

> An error is raised as the statement `import module_2` in `module_1.py` acts as if my working directory is `pkg_1` instead of `my_dir`.

First of all, when you import a package, the code in that package does not execute in a different working directory.

The second mistake is that the working directory is not relevant at all, even if it did change.

Python code is organised into packages and modules. The interpreter searches for packages and modules within the python path.

In the structure shown, `my_dir` will be in python path if you run `python src.py`. Then `pkg_1` is a package whereas `module_1` and `module_2` are modules. The easiest way to import `module_2` is to use an absolute import:

```
import pkg_1.module_2
```

Alternatively, from within another module in `pkg_1` you can use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from . import module_2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys;

# get path to this file.
path_this_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__));
# add path to import files.
sys.path.insert(0, path_this_file + "/pkg_1");

import module_1, module_2;
```

Comment: This is the thing which you definitely should not do! This is just _"I don't understand how Python imports are used correctly, so I'll invent my own overcomplicated way to use them"_